# Can I add linear gradient to background color of a text in css

Tags: css

I want to add linear gradient to the background color of a text in CSS.
I know that linear gradient is an image.
Here is my code that does not work.
Is there another way to accomplish this?

`<h1 style"background-color: linear-gradient(red, yellow);">Linear Gradient - Top to Bottom`

Please help out.

Comment: You are right that linear-gradient is an image so look into background-image CSS property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly to the text like that, but you can use `background-clip` to achieve that.

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h2>COLORFUL TEXT</h2>
```

If you want to color only the text background then just added to the text background. simple. Don't use `background-color` just use `background`

```css
 h2 {
 text-align: center;
      background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);      
    }
```

```html
    <h2>COLORFUL TEXT</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks but the text is hidden behind the gradient. I wanted the gradient to be behind of text.

Comment: you mean the text background? @Phyln

Comment: if you want to apply it to text background, then don't use `background-color`. just use `background`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Good one. Thanks @Mad7Dragon. It helped. I knew I could do many things with CSS.